# Generic autovivify function for Maps

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, autovivification

How can I create vivify a key with generics? This code does not even compile:

```
/* populate the map with a new value if the key is not in the map */
private <K,V> boolean autoVivify(Map<K,V> map, K key)
{
  if (! map.containsKey(key))
  {
    map.put(key, new V());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This seems to compile (not tested): `(V)(map.getClass().getTypeParameters()[1].getClass()).newInstance()`

Answer (score 5):

In Java-8 it's reasonable to provide a `Supplier` and use [`computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
private <K,V> boolean autoVivify(Map<K,V> map, K key, Supplier<V> supplier) {
    boolean[] result = {true};
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {
      result[0] = false;
      return supplier.get();
    });
    return result[0];
}
```

Usage example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
autoVivify(map, "str", ArrayList::new);
```

Note that unlike `containsKey/put` solutions using `computeIfAbsent` is safe for concurrent maps: no race condition will occur.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell the method how to create the value.

```
interface Producer<T> {

    T make();
}

private <K, V> boolean autoVivify(Map<K, V> map, K key, Producer<V> maker) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, maker.make());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively - use `null`. `HashMap` can contain `null` although `TreeMap` may have difficulties.

```
private <K, V> boolean autoVivify(Map<K, V> map, K key) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, null);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually `TreeMap` can contain null if it's created with null-friendly comparator.

Comment: @TagirValeev - Even for the value? Surely strange things will happen because several methods of `TreeMap` are defined to return `null` if the key is not found.

Comment: Ah, sorry. For values you even don't need the comparator. TreeMap supports null values perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If `V` have a constructor without argument you can use reflection to create an instance

```
private <K, V> boolean autoVivify(Map<K, V> map, K key, Class<V> clazz) throws Exception {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, clazz.getConstructor().newInstance());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
autoVivify(map, 3, String.class);
```